# Firebase setValue() method is not triggered sometimes while using diskpersistence

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While using firebase with disk persistence enabled in android, I observed sometimes the data added using setValue() method is not reflected in the database.The code is just simple firebaseRef.child("xyz").setValue(userObj).Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. Do you have steps that I can use to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: The steps are: 1)set disk persistence enabled in app java file, 2)get information from user via editTextView and then call setValue on a firebase url. Although the frequency of the problem is less, but even so I want to at least show the user an error message. So, how can I know if the value has been written to the database for sure?

Answer (score 2):

Your updated question from the comments is:

> how can I know if the value has been written to the database for sure?

For this you add a completion listener to the `setValue()` call. From the [documentation on completion listeners](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback):

```
ref.setValue("I'm writing data", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
    if (firebaseError != null) {
      System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    } else {
      System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks frank, I din't knew about that listener. Can you tell me in which case I might be getting this problem of data not being saved.

Comment: @Frank My similar code doesnot work when the app is offline. Any clue why this happens?